# Does electric resistance of an iron-cored electromagnet depend upon the size and type of the core?

Tags: resistance, electromagnetism, electromagnet

I know that the resistance of an electromagnet depends upon the nature, length, and diameter of the wire. Is it also depend upon the size and nature of the iron core on which the wire is wrapped?

Comment: What type of electromagnet application is it?

Comment: A fatter core means each turn is longer, so in that case, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resistance would be the same, but the inductance would increase.  The current will be the same if you're driving it with DC, but would probably decrease slightly if you're driving it with AC.

Answer (score 0):

The DC resistance is not affected by the core or the material the core is composed of.  As you said: it is affected by the material, length, diameter of the wire.  Note that temperature also affects the resistance.

However, the core material DOES affect the AC impedance of the winding.